# How to communicate from class library

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, class-library

I'm having some trouble conceptualizing what I'm supposed to do to facilitate communication between my class library and programs that use it -- in this case, a Windows Forms app:

```
// Class in library
class Foo()
{
    public Foo(){}

    public void DoWork()
    {
        log("Working...");
    }

    private void log( string s )
    {
        Console.Writeline(s);
    }

}

// Forms App
class Form1()
{
    public Form1()
    {
        Foo MyFoo = new Foo();
        MyFoo.DoWork();
    }
}
```

Since there is nothing listening to the console in a winforms app, calls to log() show nothing.  Is there a way to dynamically overwrite the Foo.Log method, or possibly assign a method with that signature to the Foo object that is more suitable for a forms app at runtime?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declare a logger interface and inject a concrete logger into the library class

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}

public class Foo
{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public Foo (ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoWork ()
    {
        _logger.Log("Working...");
    }
}
```

Use it like this

```
var foo = new Foo(new ConsoleLogger());
var foo = new Foo(new FileLogger());
var foo = new Foo(new MsgBoxLogger());
```

Where all these loggers implement the interface.

```
public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
{
    public void Log(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE

As Mike Panter has pointed out already, you can use a delegate

```
public class Foo
{
    private Action<string> _writeLog;

    public Foo (Action<string> writeLog)
    {
        _writeLog = writeLog;
    }

    public void DoWork ()
    {
        _writeLog("Working...");
    }
}
```

you can call it like this

```
var foo = new Foo(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Advantages of the delegate injection

- Very simple to declare
- Very simple to use
- You can pass additional parameters through variable capturing.

See Jon Skeets article [The Beauty of Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter5/closures.aspx) for variable capturing.

Advantages of the interface injection

- You can easily pass parameters to the logger through its constructor, like a file name for the FileLogger. Since the constructor is not part of the interface, different loggers can have different constructor parameters.
- You can easily test it with unit tests, what you cannot do with anonymous lambda expressions, since there is no way to access them from the unit test.
- You can use a mock logger in unit tests of your library classes.
- You can create a new specialized logger by deriving it from an existing one.
- You can declare private helper methods within a logger.

Comment: Note: You can see the console output of a WinForms program in the Ouput window of Visual Studio.

Comment: I added an update comparing intreface versus delegate injection.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, declare a delegate function, and get the caller to set it to something suitable for the context, like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public delegate void Log(string s);

    public Log LoggingDelegate;

    public void DoWork() 
    { 
        LoggingDelegate("Working..."); 
    } 
} 

class Program
{
    private static void Log( string s ) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(s); 
    } 

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myFoo = new Foo();
        myFoo.LoggingDelegate = Log;
        myFoo.DoWork(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for this input. This is actually what I was thinking I'd have to do, but I didn't know how to do it.  I appreciate your posting!

Answer (score 1):

**Based on the question before it was edited:**

The method `doWork()` of class `foo` is `private`. You cannot call it from outside your class library. You have to access it through a `public` method, or make it `public`.

Check out [Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Hmm..I don't think that's quite what I'm trying to do.  Maybe I'm not asking the right question. Based on the nature of the calling program, I'd like to be able to assign a method to the foo object named DoWork whose context would be appropriate for the program that's calling it. That way, the new method would be used any time its called within the Foo object.

Comment: @ajax81 I don't see how you can call an external method without marking it as `public`. If the method needs to know the context of the calling program, consider passing appropriate parameters as arguments to the method.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Typo on my part -- doWork() is now public.

Comment: @ajax81 As Olivier has explained in his answer, you'll need to "inject" the context for you to be able to get meaningful results.

Comment: @TC: Excellent. Thanks for taking the time!